# Неверная кодировка при чтении файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Что делать, если при чтении файла (текста в формате .txt) и выводе с помощью функции print(), кириллица  превращается в непонятные символы?

[image: Пример]

Исходный код:

```
file = open('text.txt','r')
text = file.read()
print(text)
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в "Блокноте" кодировка показывается правильная, значит у файла родная кодировка `Windows` - `cp1251`, эту кодировку и нужно указать при открытии файла:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file:
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 5):

Когда открываете файл - делайте это с правильной кодировкой. Если у вас входной файл в кодировке `utf8`, то вот так:

```
file = open('text.txt','r', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Кодировка `utf-8` используется в `python 3` по умолчанию

Comment: @CrazyElf У меня под Windows кодировка по умолчанию в которой `python3` открывает файлы - это `1251`. Видимо зависит от ОС, а скорее всего от текущей locale.

Comment: Хм, возможно я не прав, завтра проверю )

Comment: @CrazyElf Я проверял - получал именно такие кракозябры если открывал файл без явного указания кодировки или с `1251`. И нормальный текст если указывал `utf-8`. Входной файл был в UTF8.

Comment: @CrazyElf, если кодировка не задана явно, `open()` открывает файл в кодировке, которую возвращает `locale.getpreferredencoding()` ;)

Answer (score 4):

[Из официальной документации по функции `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open):

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is
> platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to
> get the current locale encoding.

Т.е. кодировка по умолчанию может отличаться от системы к системе.

Соответственно если файл сохранен в кодировке отличающейся от той, которую возвращает функция `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, тогда лучше явно задать правильную кодировку при открытии файла.